# Sqlite3 error when inserting using dataframe columns - Sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

My **sql_insert** statement is:

```
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2) VALUES (?,?)"
```

I am trying to insert values into columns of a sqlite3 database using the following statement:

```
c.execute(sql_insert, (df['col1'], df['col2']))
```

Error I am getting is:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Shape of my dataframe 'df' is (1000,2) i.e. 1000 rows and 2 columns Col1 and Col2. I think problem perhaps is that Sqlite3 does not accept df['col1'] i.e. Python Series type input while inserting records, but I am not sure if I have characterized the problem correctly.

Can someone help? I know that I can direct convert my Dataframe to Sqlite3 db using .to_sql, and I can use that as a last resort if providing values like df['col1'] don't work.

Comment: What is the type of `myTable.col1` in the database, and what is the type of `df['col1']` in the code?

Comment: created them as integer.